# Does Firebase's free tier expire?

Tags: firebase

Many cloud services' free tiers expire within a certain number of months. For example, AWS free tier expires after 12 months.

I'm wondering if Firebase's free tier expire after a certain period of time given that I do not reach the free tier quota.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase does not expire.

Only differences between paid and free account is, paid account gets more storage, bandwidth, hosting space etc than free account.

Reference : https://firebase.google.com/pricing/

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no expiration.  Everything on the [pricing page](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/) is exactly as stated, there are no hidden costs or limits that I'm aware of.  Please reach out to [Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/) for canonical billing details.